# Where to get 12V from my computer?

Tags: power-supply, computers

Since I am having some trouble with a battery pack and a charger I want to use for a home robotics project I got a tip to just use some alternative power source and buy a new battery and charger once my project has proceeded a bit. The alternate power source that was suggested was my PCs PSU. So I unscrewed my computer and got a lot of louse ends.

My question is now: from which ends can I take 12V?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't have been a problem when you scaled these images down ;-)

Comment: A multimeter will give you a definite answer. It's good to have one around to troubleshoot other problems too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the pinout of a standard ATX power supply](http://www.smpspowersupply.com/connectors-pinouts.html). You can take from the +12V pins. Note that I believe for most PSU you'll have to short PS_ON to COM if you want it to turn on outside of the computer.

*[image removed due to a DMCA request by the copyright holder]*

Answer (score 6):

YMMV but I'd use something like this

https://www.google.com/search?q=atx+bench+adapter

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much power you need, the answer would vary, but the easiest place would probably be from the molex connector:

[image: https://www.icmag.com/ic/picture.php?albumid=7678&pictureid=191268]

This is mostly a legacy connector that isn't used much in current computers, and has nice, thick wires, allowing for easy access.